# Google Analytics core reporting API v4 PHP library method/function reference

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

It seems counterintuitive, however it looks like global reference for Google Analytics reporting API v4 PHP library does not exist. Google developer support has a couple of small pages only: one with a quick start guide, another with a few examples. Not nearly enough if one wants to utilize the library.

Is there any function reference guide for functions/methods of this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see it here [AnalyticsReporting](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Service/AnalyticsReporting.php)

The examples for the library can be found on the analytics documentation page [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)

```
// Create the DateRange object.
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2015-06-15");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2015-06-30");

// Create the Metrics object.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("sessions");

//Create the Dimensions object.
$browser = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
$browser->setName("ga:browser");

// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId("XXXX");
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setDimensions(array($browser));
$request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

$body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
$body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
return $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );
```

There is even a [quick start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php)

Comment: Thank you. Before posting the question I went through both quickstart and documentation page. The report object is pretty big and I would love to see its structure (already solved it by parsing `$report` object with `print("<pre>". print_r( get_object_vars ($report), true)."</pre>");`  as well as all the possible methods (which you have kindly provided).

Comment: You can always check the source code on the library just remember to take the v1-master branch and not the master branch which is used for composer